# Want to have BOTH case insensitve AND ^~ (stop regex)

Tags: nginx

I am configuring an nginx server on Ubuntu 19.04.  I want to have a location with BOTH modifiers  ^~  AND   ~*  I want to stop looking at locations with the ^~ and want to be case insensitive.  I have a requirement to stop searching for locations.  Is this possible?

location ^~ /videos  {
// This works, but I also want this case insensitive.

}

Comment: Regular expression locations are evaluated in order. If you want to stop matching other regular expressions, simply place this regular expression location before any other regular expression locations. There is no case insensitive prefix location.